# How to push key values into an array and pop out last duplicate key value entered?

Tags: javascript

I am collecting data from html form as radio buttons are clicked and pushing into an array as name value pairs.

I need to retain the latest data pushed by doing a pop of the previous name value selected if it already exists in the array.

In the below HTML, I need one name/value from each group.

How do I pop the previous value if the current selection matches?

I need a ***plain JavaScript solution only.***

*Group A: Color.*

```
        <p class="question">What is your favorite color?</p>

        <p>
            <input type="radio" id="red" name="color" value="Red">
            <label for="red">Red</label>
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="radio" id="blue" name="color" value="Blue">
            <label for="blue">Blue</label>
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="radio" id="green" name="color" value="Green">
            <label for="green">Green</label>
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="radio" id="yellow" name="color" value="yellow">
            <label for="yellow">Yellow</label>
        </p>
```

*Group B: Weather:*

```
        <p class="question">What is your favorite weather?</p>

        <p>
            <input type="radio" id="summer" name="weather" value="Summer">
            <label for="summer">Summer</label>
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="radio" id="winter" name="weather" value="Winter">
            <label for="winter">Winter</label>
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="radio" id="spring" name="weather" value="Spring">
            <label for="spring">Spring</label>
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="radio" id="fall" name="weather" value="Fall">
            <label for="fall">Fall</label>
        </p>
```

*Javascript:*

```
var answer = [];

var option = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var output = document.getElementById('output');

for (var i = option.length; i--;) {

    option[i].addEventListener('click', function () {

        for (var i = 0; i < option.length; i++) {
            if (option[i].type == 'radio' && option[i].checked) {

                answer.push({name: option[i].name, value: option[i].value});

            }
        }
         // Alert for demo only.
        alert(JSON.stringify(answer));

    }, false);
}
```

In the below screen shot, I need only the highlighted data:

[image]

Fiddle: [Push key values into an array.(Example)](http://jsfiddle.net/g9ptg35p/)

Comment: just use an object; they self-reconcile old keys... `{weather:"Winter", color:"Red"}`

Comment: what is the use case for the array?

Comment: The final data from the array will get inserted into a DB. I am thinking it's better to get things clean up on the client before sending to the DB.

Comment: I attempted to use an object but I need both name and value from each group. An object will give me a single name value. In this case I need one set from `colors` and another from `weather`.

Comment: The answer by dandavis has two names and two values. Why are you saying it only gives you "a single name value"?